# single mode fiber, multimode fiber working

Tags: fiber

I find the difference between the production of Single mode fiber and multi-mode fiber.In the single mode fiber the light beam is shown to travel straight,how does total internal reflection happens in it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path the light takes isn't actually straight, it just follows closer to the center than with multimode fibers due to the fact that the fiber itself is much thinner. It does still hit the side of the fiber when it curves.